# Copy range from one sheet and insert into another

Tags: excel, vba

I simply need to copy from A1 to Q9 from sheet "Header" and insert such range into sheet "Master_Sheet" inthe same range.
I say insert because at the time the above macro is called, the range has data in it and I do not have to cancel the content.
I tried something along these lines that I have copied but it would copy the data on top of the existing once and I need instead to insert them with formatting. Obviopusly I do not know VBA.

```
Sub Main()
    Sheets("Master_Sheet").Range("A1:Q9").Value = Sheets("Header").Range("A1:Q9").Value
End Sub
```

Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code copies the values alone not formatting. if you want copy the data with formatting try the below code it should work

```
     Sub Main()
        Dim lrow As Integer

        With Sheets("Header")
        lrow = Sheets("Master_Sheet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        .Range("A1:Q9").Copy Sheets("Master_Sheet").Range("A" & lrow + 1) ' - for cut
        End With

    End Sub
```

or if you to insert the at the begging of the cell (A1 - in master sheet)

Use below code

```
Sub Macro3()
    Sheets("Header").Range("A1:Q9").Copy
    Sheets("Master_Sheet").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

The above code copies the data from A1:Q9 from header sheet and paste at the end of master sheet A column

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it does exactly the contrary. It is copying the range from Master_Sheet into Header.I have just swapped the sheets names and it is fine except that it is copyng and not inserting.

Comment: Ohps...it is copying not inserting. Please help

Comment: You mean cut and paste ?

Comment: I do not need to cut. I need to insert the range into Master_Page. At the time I run the Macro, the Master_Page has data in it starting from A1 so I need to make spage for the above mentioned range otherwhise it gets copied on existing data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49670/discussion-between-nullbyte-and-sathish-k)